# Select unique records from child with condition on parent relationship

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have two tables, Shows and Episodes, each episode has show_id linking them one to many.

Now I need to get latest 6 episodes, one per show, where show.active is true

I've tried the following code:

```
$episodes = Episode::select(DB::raw('t.*'))
        ->from(DB::raw('(SELECT * FROM episodes ORDER BY id DESC) t'))
        ->whereHas('show', function($query) {
            $query->where('active', '=', true);
        })
        ->groupBy('t.show_id')
        ->take(6)
        ->get();
```

Unfortunately, I get the following:

Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'episodes.show_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select t.* from (SELECT * FROM episodes ORDER BY id DESC) t where exists (select * from `shows` where `episodes`.`show_id` = `shows`.`id` and `active` = 1) group by `t`.`show_id` limit 6)

I've also tried:

```
$episodes = Episode::where('active', true)
        ->orderBy('id', 'DESC')
        ->whereHas('show', function($query) {
            $query->where('active', '=', true);
        })
        ->groupBy('show_id')
        ->take(6)
    ->get();
```

It shows no error, but doesn't return latest of each show, groupBy gets the first record, I need the latest

Comment: Instead of groupBy('show_id') try orderBy('show_id', 'desc')

Comment: @andreeab Unfortunately, this doesn't solve the problem, error still exists

Comment: did you tried on the first code or the second?

Comment: @andreeab on first code it won't change anything, as code has an error, however, on second code, it doesn't show error but it doesn't return unique records, which groupBy does

Comment: What database and version are you using?

Comment: MySQL 5.6.37 version @JonasStaudenmeir

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
            $episodes = Episode::where('active', true)
                ->whereHas('show', function($query) {
                    $query->where('active', '=', true);
                })
                ->groupBy('show_id')
                ->orderBy('id', 'DESC')
                ->take(6)
            ->get();
```

Comment: Thanks for your attempts, unfortunately it gives same result as my second solution which is not what I want, I want latest records.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
$episodes = Episode::selectRaw('max(id) as id, show_id')
                ->whereHas('show', function($query) {
                    $query->where('active', '=', true);
                })
                ->orderBy('id', 'DESC')
                ->groupBy('show_id')
                ->take(6)
                ->get();
```

Comment: Yes it retrieves correct podcasts, but only the 'id' column, I need the entire row. Thanks in advance

Comment: @MahmoudTarek you need to specify the column in the select function like this `selectRaw('max(id) as id, show_id', 'col1', 'col2')`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `WHERE IN` subquery:

```php
$ids = Episode::selectRaw('max(id)')
    ->whereHas('show', function ($query) {
        $query->where('active', '=', true);
    })->groupBy('show_id');

$episodes = Episode::whereIn('id', $ids)
    ->take(6)
    ->get();
```